# Hatcher's Algebraic topology, section 2.2 exerise 26, page 157

Tags: algebraic-topology

In part (a) of this question, we show that $X$ is a retract of $X \cup CA$ if and only if $A$ is contractible in $X$. Then in part (b), the question is to show that if $A$ is contractible in $X$ then $H_n(X,A) \approx \widetilde{H}_n(X) \oplus \widetilde{H}_{n-1}(A)$. But this doesn't seem right. My reasoning is something like this: we have $H_n(X,A) \approx \widetilde{H}_n(X \cup CA)$, c.f. page 125 in the text, after proposition 2.22. Then the assumption $A$ is contractible in $X$ implies $X$ is a retract of $X \cup A$ by part (a), in which case, one should have $\widetilde{H}_n(X \cup A) \approx \widetilde{H}_n(X)$ where isomorphism is given by $r_*$ and $i_*$ where $r : X \cup CA \rightarrow X$ is the retract and $i : X \rightarrow X \cup CA$ is inclusion. So shouldn't the statement be $H_n(X,A) \approx \widetilde{H}_n(X)$ i.e. there is no term $\widetilde{H}_{n-1}(A)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being a retract only implies a monomorphism on homology, not an isomorphism.  As an example, consider $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $A = S^1$.  Clearly $A$ is contractible in $X$ (since $X$ is contractible itself), but if you form $X \cup CA$, you get something homeomorphic to $S^2$.  To answer the question, consider the long exact sequence in homology.